# How can I extract the URL Paths from a html file? (In bash)

Tags: regex, bash, url, path

I have the file `urls-list.html` with multiples URL paths inside, in this format:

```
   <body contenteditable="true">
      <h1>File: <a href="https://test.com/Config.js" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">https://test.com/Config.js</a></h1>
      <div>
         <a href='/common/assets/locale/language_en.props' class='text'>/common/assets/locale/language_en.props</a>
         <div class='container'>                        urls: [e.get("app.content.domain") + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>/common/assets/locale/language_en.props</span>"]</div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href='/common/assets/locale/language_en1.props' class='text'>/common/assets/locale/language_en1.props</a>
         <div class='container'>                            remote: a + n + brandSuffix + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>>/common/assets/locale/language_en1.props</span>",</div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href='/common/assets/locale/language_en2.props' class='text'>/common/assets/locale/language_en2.props</a>
         <div class='container'>                            remote: a + n + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>>/common/assets/locale/language_en2.props</span>",</div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href='/common/assets/locale/language_en2.props' class='text'>/common/assets/locale/language_en2.props</a>
         <div class='container'>                            remote: a + n + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>>/common/assets/locale/language_en3.props</span>",</div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href='/common/assets/locale/language_en3.props' class='text'>/common/assets/locale/language_en3.props</a>
         <div class='container'>                            remote: a + n + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>>/common/assets/locale/language_en4.props</span>",</div>
      </div>
      <div>
     <a href='/main' class='text'>/main</a>
     <div class='container'>                    versionedAssets.isEnabled() &amp;&amp; (i = versionedAssets.getJSAsset("dashboard/boot"), r = versionedAssets.getJSAsset("dashboard<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>"), l = versionedAssets.getJSAsset("appkit-utilities<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>"), hybrid &amp;&amp; (i = versionedAssets.getHybridAsset("dashboard/boot"), r = versionedAssets.getHybridAsset("dashboard<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>"))), envProps.get("app.blueJSVersion.enabled") ? (n.push([envProps.get("app.blueVendor.version") + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>", envProps.get("app.blue.version") + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>", envProps.get("app.blueApp.version") + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>", envProps.get("app.blueView.version") + "<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>", "blue-ui/dist/blue-ui/js<span style='background-color:yellow'>/main</span>", l, i, r]), n.push([{</div>
  </div>
```

I like help to extract all URLs Paths showing inside the `span` tags from the file urls-list.html.

To be more clear I need this output:

```
    Command: ./extra-path.sh urls-list.html (or simialr)
    result:
    /common/assets/locale/language_en.props
    /common/assets/locale/language_en1.props
    /common/assets/locale/language_en2.props
    /main
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE: I only need the URL paths from with yellow. (background-color:yellow)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help you on same.

```
cat script.ksh
awk '/span/ && match($0,/<span style=\047background-color:yellow\047>>[^<]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+39,RLENGTH-39)}'  "$1"
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
cat script.ksh
awk '
/span/ && match($0,/<span style=\047background-color:yellow\047>>[^<]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+39,RLENGTH-39)
}'   "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13 I try this and it works but didn't  work with the html file I have.  I just upload a new file input. I only need the `href=`

Comment: Sorry @RavinderSingh13 This was my bad. This is the correct input. I apologize

Comment: I like to add that all paths are inside span tag with `background-color:yellow`

Comment: Thank but the edit didn't get them. This is large html file with lots of different < > tags. I only need the paths inside `background-color:yellow`

Comment: Din't work it return  `div div div div div div div div div`

Comment: here the script execution:

awk -F"[><]" '/background-color:yellow/{print $2}'  file.html 
div
div
div
div
div
div

Comment: Yes the html file has `div` and all sort of different tags and among them you can find the urls paths inside span tag with background-color:yellow

Comment: I reproduce the bug a was getting. with div. I just upload the input with a more full version. please have a look.

Comment: It did work but din't work on my large file.  I upload the Input for last time. Now I'm 100% sure I upload the correct input. I'm not sure why your script didn't work on this version.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var href = window.location.href;
var dir = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in bash using awk:

```
awk -F'[ =]' '/href/ {print $3}' urls-list.html
```

Explanation:
*-F* tells awk to use spaces and '=' as delimiters
*/href/* makes the print command run on every line that contains "/href/"
*print $3* prints the third token

However, this will work only when the input line format is exactly the same as in your example. Something more robust would be:

```
awk -F'href=' '/href/ {print $2}' urls-list.html | awk -F'[ <>]' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Paza your bash works. But I didn't get the result I was looking. 
 I just upload the input. This is my fault. Can you give hand?

Comment: Hi @pancho, after the edit you made, I can't make out the relation between the input and output

Comment: please now have a look of the input and the output